# maven update version number automatically with buildNumber plugin

Tags: maven, buildnumber-maven-plugin, versions-maven-plugin

After watching some videos about setting up CI & CD and maven I tried to find the right order of how to use maven plugins in the release process.

I set up a CI & CD chain before but it was with gradle, so the part that is the most confusing to me is the maven part.

To explain:

I got the maven-version-plugin manage the automatic dependency upgrading for the releases.

I got the buildnumber-maven-plugin to get the build number as patch version number for the releases.

I want to use maven release to create the release.

First I want to set the version in a multi module (all modules are in one git repo btw) environment to per module major.minor.patch version pattern.
Major and minor should be settable by hand per module. The patch version should be the git build number.

What I tried was to set the  node to e.g. 1.0.${buildNumber} but this causes all sorts of problems.

My next idea was in the line of writing the buildnumber in a property file via buildnumber:create-metadata
then use this in the maven release plugin somehow
and then using the version plugin to update.

But I am not quite sure how to start on this triangle.

What is the proper way to use the build number together with the maven version plugin for automatically updating version ranges for dependencies and then use maven release plugin to build a release?

If someone could push me in the right direction it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this plugin [maven ci friendly](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html). It has 3 tags that can be used.

- revision
- sha1
- changelist (this can potentially contain your build number)

It also has multi-module project setup guide on the same page.